# Why doesn't the <input> element respect min-width?

Tags: html, css

http://jsbin.com/nuzazefuwi/1/edit?html,css,output

In the link above the textbox should have only 10px instead it has a width of `152px`.

This is the code:

```css
.input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cont {
  padding: 2px;
}

.main {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='cont'>
    <input type="text" class='input' />
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/> the textbox should have 10px
```

It looks like the input starts to get the correct width only after `.main` `min-width` is greater than 156px.

Comment: set `border:0; outline:0` for `input`

Comment: you want input field width should be 10px ? really but how?

Comment: In your demo  textbox appear 100%.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how/why would that be 10px? Nowhere in your code have you used any sort of width declaration?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

There is **`size="20"`** set on [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) type `text`, `search`, `tel`, `url`, `email`, and `password` ... by default, which is approximately of `100px` width, although it can vary in a different browser and operating system.

On the parent, you have `min-width:15px;` set, that does not take any effects, because the value is much smaller than `100px`. If you change it to `width:15px;` or `max-width:15px;` you will then see the differences.

Alternatively you can give the `size` a very small value such as **`size="1"`**.

Comment: Upvote for for `size="1"`. Not something I have ever come across but super helpful to get an input down to a small width (edge case, but needed sometimes).

Comment: size="1" should be a standard "reset" param for any flexible component development. This "secret" min-width that I could not get rid of with CSS (other than explicit width) was being a huge pain before I applied size=1. Thanks!

Comment: Note: `size="0"` does not work, and from what I can tell there is no way to remove this entirely so it is impossible to go smaller than `size="1"`.  

Comment: Additionally, if it's an `<input type="number" />`, then `size` won't work, you need to set `min` _and_ `max` (which obviously also means it's going to be form validated, so only set it, if it's appropriate). Setting a `maxlength` does _not_ work (at least on iOS).

Answer (score 0):

You have a `min-width` set, but no `max-width`.

The textbook has a default size set by the browser. That default size in greater than the `min-width`, so the both the browser and the css are happy to let that default width take place and increase the width of the container.

By setting a `max-width` or a `width` for the container, the container's and input's size will be restricted and their sizes will be computed accordingly.

```
.main{
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid black;
  min-width:14px;
  max-width:140px; // What do you want here?
}
```

I think this is also what @sdcr answered and he also gave you details about the default size and computations.

Answer (score 0):

Each element has a **width** and a **min-width**, they are different when you have a parent with a **min-width** and a child with a `width:100%`, the child will inherit from the parent its **width**, **which can be equal to the ***min-width*** at some point**, but if the child has a **min-width** by default, then the child will stick to its **min-width**. *(in this case input has default size which sets its **min-width** to somewhere around 150px)*

**My solution was to give input:**

```css
 input { min-width: 0 }
```

Answer (score -1):

change your css width as 155px

```
.input{  
  width:155px;  //Replace 100% to 155px
 box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```

Comment: I need the width of the .input to be 100%, I'm actually using atm a js workaround to hide the input, get the width of the .main and set the width of the .input; I was wondering if there's some css rule I've missed

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't think this would work, but setting `width: 0` does allow the input element to be shrunk fully assuming it is inside a flexbox. The actual width of the element itself won't be 0 if the flex is set to be higher than 0.

Answer (score -2):

The `.main` container spans the width of the content inside and only if you resize the screen to small size you will see that the `input` actually fits inside with smaller than the default input width. If you change the `width` of the `.main` content you will observe that the `input` changes it's default `width` on large screen and shrinks to no less than the `min-width` value.

```
.main{
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 75px;
  min-width:15px;  
}
```

http://jsbin.com/xeyupinaja/3/edit