# How to affect minimal width of the HTML5 progress element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29470676/2715716) which deals with `input` elements having intrinsic minimal width determined by the `size` parameter.

I am trying to design a layout where there is an `inline-flex` with `flex-direction: column` block like this:

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="item">
    short
    <progress />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    long on long so long yes long very long certainly longer than the default width of a progress
    <progress />
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  I want the first progress to be as long as the text "short" is.
</p>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y54a1udj/)

When the text is long, the `progress` correctly stretches across the available width which is determined by the length of the text because the parent `div` is `inline-flex` so it by itself won't stretch in its parent horizontally.

However when the text is very short, the `progress` doesn't shrink to the same length the text has. Instead, it stays at some (probably UA specific) minimum. I can affect its width with `width`, but than needs a fixed number, I need it to follow the lead of the text and copy its width.

In the case of the `input` in the linked question, one could set a small `size` and problem solved, however, with `progress`, no such attribute exists.

Is there a way to solve this layouting issue so that the progress width always follows the text width?

Comment: Can't you just give it a width of 100%? `<progress style="width: 100%"></progress>`.

Comment: Added code and Fiddle. Width of 100 % won't work, because the progress is what gives the parent the value of width which would be those 100 %. I want it to be shorter, as short as the top atop it.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hkb45qmf/) not what you're looking for? The progress bar matches the width of the text. Also it is not a self closing tag so it should be `<progress></progress>` not `<progress />`.

Comment: I am looking for a way to make the first progress, the one underneath the word "short" as long as the word "short" is, width-wise. If the word changes (say to "short etc.", the progress bar should still copy the width of the text i.e. it should not be hardcoded.

Comment: @sallf, the confusion may be arising because your code sample works in Chrome and Edge, but not Firefox. Same as my answer. OP must be testing in FF.

Comment: My apologies, it didn't occur to me that such a basic thing could work differently in different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Michael_B answer here is another *hack* that will force the width of the `progress` tag to be `100%` and it will work on firefox too:

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

progress {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="item">
    short
    <progress></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    long on long so long yes long very long certainly longer than the default width of a progress
    <progress></progress>
  </div>
</div>
<p>I want the first progress to be as long as the text "short" is.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

*Note that as of this writing, the solution below works in Chrome and Edge, but not Firefox.*

Add this to your code:

```
progress { width: auto }
```

Now the `progress` element will track the width of its inline-level parent.

Browsers set a default width on the `progress` element. Chrome uses `width: 10em`.

[image]

By setting your own width you override the default.

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

progress {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="item">
    short
  <progress></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    long on long so long yes long very long certainly longer than the default width of a progress
    <progress></progress>
  </div>
</div>
<p>I want the first progress to be as long as the text "short" is.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'd really love to see if there is a way to make this work in Firefox, too. If one doesn't pop up in a few days, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking. Nothing yet. Also, note that the `progress` element is not a [void element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements). It requires both opening and closing tags ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress)).

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer you can try this workaround for firefox : https://jsfiddle.net/4gezmord/

Comment: `width: auto` appears to now work on more recent versions of Firefox AFAICT.