# Why does the width of my input grow so much?

Tags: html, css, input, flexbox

I have an input inside a div with `flex-flow: row nowrap` inside another div with `flex-flow: column nowrap`.

Why does the input grow(on Chrome it's 188px, YMMV), even if it doesn't have `flex-grow: 1`?

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ebf0ff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  margin: 0.75rem 0.5rem;
  max-width: 464px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.input-wrapper {
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ebf0ff;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}

input {
  border: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: none;
}

input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.token-wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
}

.token-wrapper span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.separator {
  background-color: #ebf0ff;
  margin: 0.25rem 0rem 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  width: 1px;
}

.max-amount-wrapper {
  background-color: #ebf0ff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.375rem;
}

.max-amount-wrapper span {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 400;
]
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input name="amount" placeholder="0" type="number" />
    <div class="token-wrapper">
      <span>DAI</span>
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="max-amount-wrapper">
      Max&nbsp;(<span>&nbsp;84&nbsp;</span>)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any input with 188px width.

Comment: it's more than 188px for me

Comment: @Michael_B it doesn't have an outline. Maybe try hover it with the inspector?

Comment: @TemaniAfif there may be differences across browsers, it's 188px on Chrome. I edited the question body to imply that the specific width is not relevant.

Comment: I am also on chrome

Comment: What are you expecting the input's width to be? You haven't defined a length for it.

Comment: @Michael_B well I would've expected to be the length of content, i.e. the placeholder at start. Is there a default width?

Comment: Yes. `input` elements have a minimum width, as set by the browser in its default stylesheet. Use dev tools to inspect the `input`. Look for *user agent styles*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42421361/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to one of @Michael_B's comments, I managed to identify the issue. Browsers set a minimum width to `input` tags.

- [input / button elements not shrinking in a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421361/input-button-elements-not-shrinking-in-a-flex-container)
- [Why doesn't the <input> element respect min-width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470676/why-doesnt-the-input-element-respect-min-width)

I applied `width: 0` on the input and the width scaled down to the value I was expecting.